# How to remove action bar from WebView in android

Tags: android, android-layout, webview, android-webview, android-custom-view

I am using webview in android. This is working fine and showing all text properly. Now I want to add custom text copy functionality.

On long press, copy bar appears on the top of the web view but I want to remove/hide this bar and want to add my custom pop up at the above of copying text.

[image]

**Problem:**

1) How to remove the option action bar on long press

2) How to add the my custom bar at my customary position

3) How to add the functionality of copy text.

Comment: any luck regarding this issue

Comment: @manoj Do you get any solution for this to override action bar in webview